# how to get html/css snipits in backticks when using typescript for AngularJS

Tags: html, css, angularjs, typescript, backticks

i know this might kind of sound dumb but whenever i write templates in Angular 2 my html just shows up as gray text and i cant do things like autocomplete and stuff. Same issue with the CSS

Is there a plugin to solve this or is this a settings issue?

BTW im using Visual studio code

EDIT: Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Can you at least post a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin that will add this highlighting:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nwallace.language-vscode-javascript-angular2

Appears from the comments it doesn't actually support intellisense/completion in there but has syntax highlighting.  Personally use IntelliJ products for a lot of projects and they have a "language injections" option: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/using-language-injections.html Perhaps Visual Studio has something similar or you can try out IntelliJ.

Comment: hmm might give intellij a try...but isnt that a paid IDE?

Comment: Yeah but free trial, for me it's worth it for the interactive debugger for back end code and believe Android studio which is free is built on intellij

Comment: Does similar exist for Visual Studio 2015?

Answer (score 1):

Have you configured Angular Js 2 and TypeScript correctly in Visual Studio Code? 
Here's a link [link](https://medium.com/@menezes.carlos/angular-2-setting-up-your-working-environment-52b985d1d341#.wzj32tv8q/) for that.